# Excel solver won't work when a constraint is unsatisfied in the beginning

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-2010, solver

I have this:

```
A B C
2 3 A1+B1
4 5 A2+B2

constraint_1: A1 + A2 = 5
constraint_2: B1 + B2 <= 4
```

Objective cell: C3, which is `sum(C1,C2)`, it should be 0.

When I start with the state above, `A1+A2` = 6, solver won't work because constraint_1 is broken in the first place (A1+A2=6). Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: have you tried fiddling with the solver parameters and methods?

Comment: Changing cells is: A1, A2, B1, B2. And I tried with different options. no luck.

Comment: Excel 2010, By Changing Cells is: `$A$1:$A$2,$B$1:$B$2`, `A1:B2` are in number format, C1 is `=A1+B1`, C2 is `=A2+B2`, constraint_1 means sum of A1 and A2 should be equal to 5, i specify it as "A3=5" with `A3` `=sum(A1:A2)`

Comment: there are also parameters for the solver (I mean the settings for the solver itself, not the cells you refer to).

Comment: Yes, but they dont help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unchecking the "Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative" box in the Solver Parameters Dialog.  When I do this, I get a feasible solution of `A1=5`, `B1=0`, `A2=0`, `B2=-5`.

The nature of your problem is such that there is no feasible solution unless some of the variables are allowed to be negative.

Comment: OK, in my question, it was only an example. In my real problem, non of the values should be negative. Can you get it run when A1+A2 = 6 in the beginning? Because you start with a broken constraint in the beginning, A1+A2 = 6, but it should be A1+A2 = 5 ??? What I'd like to know is: will solver work when I start with a broken constraint?

Comment: Yes, it can work when you start with a broken constraint, provided there is a feasible solution to be found.  For example, it worked for me with the problem and initial conditions you gave, but only when I unchecked the "Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative" box (because there is no feasible solution to the problem you gave that does not have negative-valued variables).  If your real problem is different and you're still getting "Solver could not find a feasible solution" result, it might be instructive to relax some of your constraints (or change the objective to a Min or Max).

Comment: OK, isn't there an option to get the best approximate solution? I set the objective cell to be Value of 0, but I can also accept a value that is close to 0. Another question: why I can't select multiple objective cells? Maybe I want C3, D3 end E3 to be close to 0 as much as possible, but it allows me to select only 1 cell as Objective cell.

Comment: And, does dollar signs make any difference in "By Changing Variable Cells", and in Constraint definitions?

Comment: If you want the best approximate solution, you might set the objective to "Min" instead of "Value Of".  If your variables and objective are such that the value of the objective can be negative, you might also need to change your objective to the square or absolute value of what it currently is (although that will mean you can't use the LP Simplex method, since the problem will no longer be linear).

Comment: OK, does dollar signs make any difference in "By Changing Variable Cells", and in Constraint definitions?

Comment: You can approximate multiple objective cells by making your (single) objective some function (like a sum, sum of squares, minimum, minimum of squares, minimum of absolute values, etc.) of the cells in question.  You will need to find a reasonable way of including/weighing this along with your "real" objective.  Altenatively, you can leave or original objective unchanged and put constraints on the cells that you want to be close to zero and progressively relax these constraints if needed to find a feasible solution.

Comment: Dollar signs don't make a difference.  Excel will just add them in anyway.

Comment: I finally got it running! Thank you very much! You did a fantastic job helping me, I really really needed to get the solver working, best regards

Answer (score 0):

The constraint values need to be put in in the correct order in the solver, for example A1 = B1 might not work, but B1 = A1 will.  It depends which is a fixed value and which is the calculated value.

The calculated value should be on the left.  If you place the fixed value on the left it simply wont work.